# Bootstrap 3: adding a new set of columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, mixins

I've been using `Bootstrap 3` for a while and now I need to make a new set of extra small columns for horizontal mobiles (e.g. `384px` screen width) and after this use it as follows:

`col-xxs-1`, `col-xxs-2`, `col-xxs-offset-5`, `hidden-xxs`, etc.

Are there some `Bootstrap` `Less` mixins for this purpose? I'm not sure how to use them

edit:

There is a `Bootstrap` mixin called `.make-grid()`, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Much easier now in Bootstrap 4.x with SASS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37543791/171456

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Code for `col-xxs-x`,`col-xxs-offset`,`col-xxs-push`,`col-xxs-pull`:

**Add this code:**

```
.col-xxs-1, .col-xxs-2, .col-xxs-3, .col-xxs-4,
.col-xxs-5, .col-xxs-6, .col-xxs-7, .col-xxs-8,
.col-xxs-9, .col-xxs-10, .col-xxs-11, .col-xxs-12 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 384px) {
    .col-xxs-1,
    .col-xxs-2,
    .col-xxs-3,
    .col-xxs-4,
    .col-xxs-5,
    .col-xxs-6,
    .col-xxs-7,
    .col-xxs-8,
    .col-xxs-9,
    .col-xxs-10,
    .col-xxs-11 {
        float: left;
    }

    .col-xxs-1 {
        width: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-2 {
        width: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-4 {
        width: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-5 {
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-7 {
        width: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-8 {
        width: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-10 {
        width: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-11 {
        width: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-1 {
        left: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-2 {
        left: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-3 {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .col-xss-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-6 {
        left: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-7 {
        left: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-9 {
        left: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-10 {
       left: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-11 {
       left: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-1 {
        right: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-2 {
        right: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-3 {
        right: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-6 {
        right: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-7 {
        right: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-9 {
        right: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666666666666%;
    }
}
```

Code for `hidden-xxs`:

**Add this code:**

```
.hidden-xxs {
    display: block !important;
}

tr.hidden-xxs {
    display: table-row !important;
}

th.hidden-xxs,
td.hidden-xxs {
    display: table-cell !important;
}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xxs,
    td.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 385px) and (max-width: 767px) {

    .hidden-xxs.hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xxs.hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xxs.hidden-xs,
    td.hidden-xxs.hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .hidden-xxs.hidden-sm {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xxs.hidden-sm {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xxs.hidden-sm,
    td.hidden-xxs.hidden-sm {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    .hidden-xxs.hidden-md {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xxs.hidden-md {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xxs.hidden-md,
    td.hidden-xxs.hidden-md {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .hidden-xxs.hidden-lg {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xxs.hidden-lg {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xxs.hidden-lg,
    td.hidden-xxs.hidden-lg {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .hidden-xs.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-xs.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-xs.hidden-xxs,
    td.hidden-xs.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .hidden-sm.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-sm.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-sm.hidden-xxs,
    td.hidden-sm.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .hidden-md.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-md.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-md.hidden-xxs,
    td.hidden-md.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .hidden-lg.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    tr.hidden-lg.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }

    th.hidden-lg.hidden-xxs,
    td.hidden-lg.hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

**And also replace :**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
```

**with:**

```
@media (min-width: 385px) and (max-width: 767px) {
```

**inside bootstrap.css at this 4 blocks:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5640 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  tr.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  th.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5698 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .hidden-sm.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  tr.hidden-sm.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  th.hidden-sm.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-sm.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5756 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .hidden-md.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  tr.hidden-md.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  th.hidden-md.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-md.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5814 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .hidden-lg.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  tr.hidden-lg.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
  th.hidden-lg.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-lg.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Code for `visible-xxs`:

**Add this code:**

```
.visible-xxs {
    display: none !important;
}

tr.visible-xxs {
    display: none !important;
}

th.visible-xxs,
td.visible-xxs {
    display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 385px) and (max-width: 767px) {

    .visible-xxs.visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xxs.visible-xs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xxs.visible-xs,
    td.visible-xxs.visible-xs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .visible-xxs.visible-sm {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xxs.visible-sm {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xxs.visible-sm,
    td.visible-xxs.visible-sm {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    .visible-xxs.visible-md {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xxs.visible-md {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xxs.visible-md,
    td.visible-xxs.visible-md {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .visible-xxs.visible-lg {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xxs.visible-lg {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xxs.visible-lg,
    td.visible-xxs.visible-lg {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .visible-xs.visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-xs.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-xs.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-xs.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .visible-sm.visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-sm.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-sm.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-sm.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .visible-md.visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-md.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-md.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-md.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 384px) {

    .visible-lg.visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    tr.visible-lg.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    th.visible-lg.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-lg.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

}
```

**And also replace :**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
```

**with:**

```
@media (min-width: 385px) and (max-width: 767px) {
```

**inside bootstrap.css at this 4 blocks:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5408 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .visible-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  tr.visible-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-xs,
  td.visible-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5466 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .visible-sm.visible-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  tr.visible-sm.visible-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-sm.visible-xs,
  td.visible-sm.visible-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5524 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .visible-md.visible-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  tr.visible-md.visible-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-md.visible-xs,
  td.visible-md.visible-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { //line 5582 in default bootstrap.css v3.0.0
  .visible-lg.visible-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
  tr.visible-lg.visible-xs {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  th.visible-lg.visible-xs,
  td.visible-lg.visible-xs {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: its a good aproach, but I don't want to hardcode it (it was the 'easy' way), is there any way of using bootstrap mixins for it?

Comment: @FacundoColombier, if your hesitation to "hard-coding" is you don't want to modify Bootstrap files...then correct, you don't want to do that. Make it a separate file so that when you upgrade Bootstrap, you don't lose your changes...but for what you're asking to do paulalexandru is correct...you have to add the classes before you can use them.

Comment: @paulalexandru, I need the default sets, so the question was to add one more smaller.
You're right KevinNelson about modifying BS files, but the need of implementing pull-push-offset-visible-hidden for the new column set is more complex that paulalexandru's proposal

Comment: @paulalexandru thanks a lot for your answers, I'll try to implement your part for the columns set, but I still need the hidden/visible-xxs without having troubles with the rest of the framework, it's not that simple as you can see in this comment from mdo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203#issuecomment-23836739

Comment: Both xss and xxs seem to be used in this answer.  Is that a bug?

Comment: who need xxs offsets anyways

Comment: Found one: .col-xss-push-4 should be xxs

Comment: Another note, you forgot to make resets: .col-xxs-push-0 {left: 0%;} and .col-xxs-pull-0 {right: 0%;}

Answer (score 12):

Notice that Bootstrap's CSS uses a mobile first strategy, so it is important to define your xxs-grid (i should choose an other name) after the xs-grid but before the sm-grid. See also: [Bootstrap 3 mixin multiple make-*-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448284/bootstrap-3-mixin-multiple-make-column/26700395).

For that reason you can not use the Less code from this question [Bootstrap 3 extra large (xl) columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256977/bootstrap-3-extra-large-xl-columns/25644266)

1. Download the Bootstrap source code at: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
2. in `less/variables.less` add:

-

```
// horizontal mobiles
@screen-xxs-min:             384px;
@container-xxs: (336px + @grid-gutter-width);
```

3. Open `less/grid.less` change the `.container` class as follows:

-

```
.container {
  .container-fixed();
  @media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
    width: @container-xxs;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
```

and between the Extra small grid and Small grid code add:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
  .make-grid(xxs);
}
```

4. In the 'less/mixins/grid-framework.less' file replace twice `@item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}";` with `@item: ~".col-xs-@{index}, .col-xxs-@{index}, .col-sm-@{index}, .col-md-@{index}, .col-lg-@{index}";`
5. And finally run `grunt dist`

   6. (optional) add the following code to the `/less/mixins/grid.less` file

-

```
// Generate the small columns
.make-xxs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  @media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-xxs-column-offset(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
    margin-left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-xxs-column-push(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
    left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-xxs-column-pull(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-xxs-min) {
    right: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
```

Comment: ,could u plz check this gist https://gist.github.com/ctf0/3d9d35ffd681c924e940 and tell me if it needs anything else ?

Comment: i think you should replace `@media @xxs {
      width: @container-xxs;
  }` with `@media @xs {
      width: @container-xxs;
  }`. I'm also not sure why you using `col-lg-0-5` and so on, posible better set `@grid-columns` to 24?

Comment: setting the columns to 24 would have the same effect but would take me more time to calculate what exactly is the size like `in the 24 3 = 1.5 in the 12` ,however this still a valuable piece of info, my main question could the new `xxs` cascade up like the native without writing all the classes ? @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750661/custom-classes-for-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment43950529_27750661

Comment: changing the media query (in your gist) as suggested does not solve your issue? Could you explain your issue in more detail?

Comment: sadly it didn't ,what am after is try to give a div `col-xs-3` now that div size will be the same as if u wrote `col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3` i want that same behavior but with my new `col-xxs` class ,make any sense ?

Comment: Thanks. Would be great if you could also add the less for "hidden-xxs" and "visible-xxs"

Answer (score 3):

this full implementation (including pull-push-offset-visible-hidden) will be implemented in v4 as mentioned by [@mdo](https://github.com/mdo)

here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203#issuecomment-23823054

and here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/12893.

A posible alternative is posted here https://github.com/donquixote/bootstrap-compiled/tree/xs-AB-subdivision.

Answer (score 2):

Others have more complex solutions, but really there is an easier solution. Because this is the smallest break point, you can just add the class yourself with the !important flag so that it overrides the larger column sizes (like this). I use the name col-tn-12 because that is what this break point will be called when Bootstrap 4 is rolled out.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-tn-12 {
        width: 100% !important
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using the code from the alternative github that @facundo posted, I switched the first line from a min-width of 480px to a min-width of 0 and a max-width of 480px and it seemed to work for what I needed without having to use any other coding or files:

```
   @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:480px){
  .col-xs-B-1, .col-xs-B-2, .col-xs-B-3, .col-xs-B-4, .col-xs-B-5, .col-xs-B-6, .col-xs-B-7, .col-xs-B-8, .col-xs-B-9, .col-xs-B-10, .col-xs-B-11, .col-xs-B-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-xs-B-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-pull-0 {
    right: 0%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-push-0 {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-B-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks paulalexandru for this excellent and very usefull solution. I recently need to use the reseting offset option (col-xxs-offset-0) on smallest screens, so I had to add those few lines for it works well :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-xxs-pull-0 {
        right: 0;
    }
    .col-xxs-push-0 {
        left: 0;
    }
    .col-xxs-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

I post it here, maybe it would be usefull for thoses who may encounter this need too.

Answer (score -1):

You could just remove the media queries for the columns from the css. That would mantain the width precentage of the columns on any screen size.

Comment: I don't want to lose the other sets (xs-sm-md-lg)

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following to accomplish this.  I personally link to the bootstrap CDN in my projects and keep a local version of bootstrap so I can tap into its mixins for my site specific styles which is where I would place the following...

SCSS

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-min) {
  @include make-grid(xxs);
}
```

Less

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
  .make-grid(xxs);
}
```

Comment: that is sass (scss) code. And you don't create neither a .container class nor the column classes for your new grid.