# Twitter Bootstrap: add media queries for xxs breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I was surprised that Twitter Bootstrap does not have media queries for building an adequate website version for mobile portrait screens.

A tricky thing is to define "mobile portrait" width. Previously most phones had `320px` screen width, but currently most advisable is to target devices narrower than `375px`.

[iPhone scren resolutions](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

I need at least `.col-xxs-*` classes with a breakpoint at `375px` screen width, similar to `.col-xs-*`. This can be CSS or SCSS code. I'm using Bootstrap-4-alpha, hope solution will work for Bootstrap-3 too.

Answer (score 2):

You can **add a new breakpoint** to BS 4 by changing the `$grid-breakpoints` and `$container-max-widths` variables with SASS.

```
    /* your _custom.scss */

    @import "bootstrap/functions";
    @import "bootstrap/variables";
    @import "bootstrap/mixins";

    $grid-breakpoints: (
      xxs: 0,
      xs: 375px,
      sm: 544px,
      md: 768px,
      lg: 992px,
      xl: 1200px
    );

    $container-max-widths: (
      xxs: 375px,
      xs: 375px,
      sm: 544px,
      md: 768px,
      lg: 992px,
      xl: 1200px
    );

    @import "bootstrap";
```

http://codeply.com/go/mPS4Yros4U

**Update 2018**: Now that the `xs-` infix has been removed in Bootstrap 4, adding a new smaller xxs breakpoint means that this lowest breakpoint has no infix. For example:

```
col-6 (50% on xxs)
col-xs-6 (50% on xs)
```

**Notes on customizing Bootstrap using SASS, from the docs**...

> Modify any of the Sass variables and maps in your **custom.scss**.... Every Sass variable in Bootstrap 4 includes the !default flag allowing
>   you to override the variable’s default value in your own Sass without
>   modifying Bootstrap’s source code. Copy and paste variables as needed,
>   **modify their values, and remove the !default flag**. If a variable has
>   already been assigned, then it won’t be re-assigned by the default
>   values in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Some bootstrap forks are providing additional breakpoints in a pretty solid manner. This one seems to be maintained regularly and works fine for me:

SCSS: https://gist.github.com/Jakobud/c057577daddbde4dd709

```
// Mid-Small breakpoint

$screen-ms: 480px !default;
$screen-ms-min: $screen-ms !default;
$screen-ms-max: ($screen-sm-min - 1) !default;

// Redefined Extra Small max value (Can't override non-default variables in SASS)
$screen-xs-max-new: ($screen-ms-min - 1) !default;

// Common styles (see make-grid-columns() in bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss)

.col-ms-1,
.col-ms-2,
.col-ms-3,
.col-ms-4,
.col-ms-5,
.col-ms-6,
.col-ms-7,
.col-ms-8,
.col-ms-9,
.col-ms-10,
.col-ms-11,
.col-ms-12 {
  position: relative;
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
}

// Misc. class adjustments for col-ms

@media (min-width: $screen-ms) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
  .container {
    max-width: $screen-sm - 20px;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

// col-ms grid

@media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
  @include make-grid(ms);
}

// Visibility utilities

@include responsive-invisibility('.visible-xs, .visible-ms');

.visible-xs-block,
.visible-xs-inline,
.visible-xs-inline-block,
.visible-ms-block,
.visible-ms-inline,
.visible-ms-inline-block {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: $screen-xs-max-new) {
  @include responsive-visibility('.visible-xs');
}
.visible-xs-block {
  @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max-new) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
.visible-xs-inline {
  @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max-new) {
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
.visible-xs-inline-block {
  @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max-new) {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
  @include responsive-visibility('.visible-ms');
}
.visible-ms-block {
  @media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
.visible-ms-inline {
  @media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
.visible-ms-inline-block {
  @media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: $screen-xs-max-new) {
  @include responsive-invisibility('.hidden-xs');
}

@media (min-width: $screen-ms-min) and (max-width: $screen-ms-max) {
  @include responsive-invisibility('.hidden-ms');
}
```

LESS: https://gist.github.com/wdollar/135ec3c80faaf5a821b0

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which iPhone you're designing for, so here are most of them to help get you started

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Comment: My bad, I have forgotten that not all iPhones have screen width of `320px`. I have updated my question so that it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you can just add a new breakpoint by editing the `$grid-breakpoints`-variable. Originally it is:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

By changing it to

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xxs: 0,
  xs: 375px,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

you would add a new breakpoint `xxs`. But I would recommend a 2-sign-identifier, something like `ms` for "medium-small":

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  ms: 375px,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

In TWBS3 it's not that easy - there you will have to hack the code.