# How to create new breakpoints in bootstrap 4 using CDN?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries, frontend, bootstrap-4

I use BootstrapCDN. Other styles written in sass and built by gulp. I need to create my own breakpionts. Is it possible to make them if I use CDN? I can't figure out how to do it. I have to create these breakpoints:

```
--breakpoint-xxxs: 0;
--breakpoint-xxs: 320px;
--breakpoint-xs: 568px;
--breakpoint-sm: 667px;
--breakpoint-md: 768px;
--breakpoint-lg: 992px;
--breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
--breakpoint-xxl: 1440px;
--breakpoint-xxxl: 1600px;
```

I want to get something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-xxxs-1 col-xxs-2 col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 col-xxl-8 col-xxxl-9">
   <div style="height:100vh;background:purple">text</div>
  </div><!--col-->
 </div><!--.row-->
</div><!--.container-->
```

I found [the manual](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/06/06/how-to-create-a-new-breakpoint-in-bootstrap-4/) and I'm trying this:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
)  !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
) !default;

:root {
  --breakpoint-xxxs: 0;
  --breakpoint-xxs: 320px;
  --breakpoint-xs: 568px;
  --breakpoint-sm: 667px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --breakpoint-xxl: 1440px;
  --breakpoint-xxxl: 1600px;
}
```

But it doesn't produce results, and generates bug:

> Illegal nesting: Nothing may be nested beneath variable declarations.

[Codepen mcve](https://codepen.io/kizoso/pen/oEyeVd).

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help.

---

UPD: if that is not possible... Is there any alternative? Can I easily edit my code to simulate bootstrap grid with my breakpoints?

---

UPD2: I fixed the bugs thanks to [@aer0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924751/how-to-create-new-breakpoints-in-bootstrap-4-using-cdn/48925128#48925128):

```
$grid-breakpoints: (xxxs: 0, xxs: 320px, xs: 568px, sm: 667px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px, xxl: 1440px, xxxl: 1600px)!default

$container-max-widths: (xxxs: 0, xxs: 320px, xs: 568px, sm: 667px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px, xxl: 1440px, xxxl: 1600px)!default

\:root
  --breakpoint-xxxs: 0
  --breakpoint-xxs: 320px
  --breakpoint-xs: 568px
  --breakpoint-sm: 667px
  --breakpoint-md: 768px
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px
  --breakpoint-xxl: 1440px
  --breakpoint-xxxl: 1600px
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very surprised that there was no developer able to answer my question! Even on the [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25683) no one dared to think about it!

In fact, everything turned out to be very simple!

Yes, using the CDN we get the compiled `css` file. Styles in the bootstrap are written using sass. Moreover, the styles are written separation and modular. So it means that I do not need to load the entire bootstrap to my server. I want to deliver cached version of Bootstrap’s compiled CSS and I only need to add my breakpoints. Fortunately, there is a specific bootstrap file which is responsible for the Grid. It is `bootstrap-grid.scss`:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap Grid v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@at-root {
  @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } // stylelint-disable-line at-rule-no-vendor-prefix
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

@import "functions";
@import "variables";

@import "mixins/breakpoints";
@import "mixins/grid-framework";
@import "mixins/grid";

@import "grid";
@import "utilities/display";
@import "utilities/flex";
```

Now I just need to add sequentially the code from the files above adding my breakpoints. Add non-Grid code not necessary. For example, the code responsible for the color. [Here is my mcve at codepen](https://codepen.io/kizoso/pen/GQXawe).

Comment: You did your research on this, although I thought your question meant literally from CDN, not using SASS. This is a solution using SASS (not entirely from CDN). It's not the correct way to customize Bootstrap since it's altering the default breakpoint values. The correct method is to @import bootstrap, and then override the variable/maps in your own custom.scss which is [already explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490537/twitter-bootstrap-add-media-queries-for-xxs-breakpoint)

Comment: You'll find the smallest breakpoint isn't working, and none of the supporting grid utility classes (display, spacing, flexbox, etc...) will work when customizing this way.

Comment: @ZimSystem, At the very beginning of the article, I wrote that I use sass

Comment: @ZimSystem, You are right about the .xxxs class. Because in myxin, the smallest size removes the prefix. I fixed it, html instead of col-xxxs-1, I wrote col-1.

Answer (score 45):

It can't be done entirely from CDN. To *properly* customize/override using SASS, you need to @import the necessary Bootstrap scss files in your `custom.scss`. To override the grid-breakpoints, at a minimum you need `functions` and `variables`. Then set the variables as needed, and finally @import bootstrap. Notice how default! has been removed as [explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) as the correct customization method.

```
/* import what we need to override */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

/* set the overriding variables */
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
);
$container-max-widths: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
);

/* override the !default vars with the values we set above */
@import "bootstrap";
```

With this method, we've added the new grid breakpoints, and ensured **these new breakpoints work *everywhere*** in Bootstrap including the **grid, responsive utilities for spacing, display, flexbox, alignment, positioning**, etc...

https://codeply.com/go/BIgmm1XGc2

Also see:
[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass)
[Twitter Bootstrap: add media queries for xxs breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490537/twitter-bootstrap-add-media-queries-for-xxs-breakpoint/37543791#37543791)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I can not load the entire bootstrap on the job. It must necessarily be downloaded via CDN. "The customer is always right". Although this may be useful to someone else

Comment: You must start grid breakpoints at 0, but I'd suggest removing the container max width for `xxxs` otherwise it needlessly breaks the layout between 0 and 319px.

Comment: It's important to know that using this method relieves the need to link to the original bootstrap.css. Basically the @import "bootstrap"; pulls in the original bootstrap.css and appends it prior to any custom code you have in the css file doing the import.

Answer (score 2):

As we already now - using the CDN we get the compiled `.css`.

Faced the same problem and made a little CSS extension.

For each additional breakpoint, in your .css stylesheet, which is loaded after original bootstrap 4 CDN `.css` files (to overwrite container max-width), adding a code below:

```
/* BS4 Grid XXL breakpoint */

/* adding col-xxl */
.col-xxl, .col-xxl-1, .col-xxl-2, .col-xxl-3, .col-xxl-4, .col-xxl-5, .col-xxl-6, .col-xxl-7, .col-xxl-8, .col-xxl-9, .col-xxl-10, .col-xxl-11, .col-xxl-12, .col-xxl-auto {position: relative; width: 100%; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;}

@media (min-width: 1570px){
  /* expanding BS4 max-width */
  .container {max-width: 1540px;}

  /* grid columns xxl */
  .col-xxl {-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0; flex-basis: 0; -webkit-box-flex: 1; -ms-flex-positive: 1; flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100%;}
  .col-xxl-auto {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 auto; flex: 0 0 auto; width: auto; max-width: none;}  
  .col-xxl-1 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%; flex: 0 0 8.333333%; max-width: 8.333333%;}
  .col-xxl-2 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
  .col-xxl-3 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 25%; flex: 0 0 25%; max-width: 25%;}
  .col-xxl-4 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%; flex: 0 0 33.333333%; max-width: 33.333333%;}
  .col-xxl-5 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%; flex: 0 0 41.666667%; max-width: 41.666667%;}
  .col-xxl-6 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 50%; flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%;}
  .col-xxl-7 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%; flex: 0 0 58.333333%; max-width: 58.333333%;}
  .col-xxl-8 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%; flex: 0 0 66.666667%; max-width: 66.666667%;}
  .col-xxl-9 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 75%; flex: 0 0 75%; max-width: 75%;}
  .col-xxl-10 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
  .col-xxl-11 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
  .col-xxl-12 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}

  /* order xxl */
  .order-xxl-0 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1; -ms-flex-order: 0; order: 0;}
  .order-xxl-1 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2; -ms-flex-order: 1; order: 1;}
  .order-xxl-2 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3; -ms-flex-order: 2; order: 2;}
  .order-xxl-3 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4; -ms-flex-order: 3; order: 3;}
  .order-xxl-4 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5; -ms-flex-order: 4; order: 4;}
  .order-xxl-5 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6; -ms-flex-order: 5; order: 5;}
  .order-xxl-6 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 7; -ms-flex-order: 6; order: 6;}
  .order-xxl-7 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 8; -ms-flex-order: 7; order: 7;}
  .order-xxl-8 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 9; -ms-flex-order: 8; order: 8;}
  .order-xxl-9 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 10; -ms-flex-order: 9; order: 9;}
  .order-xxl-10 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 11; -ms-flex-order: 10; order: 10;}
  .order-xxl-11 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 12; -ms-flex-order: 11; order: 11;}
  .order-xxl-12 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 13; -ms-flex-order: 12; order: 12;}

  /* text-align xxl */
  .text-xxl-center {text-align: center!important;}
  .text-xxl-left {text-align: left!important;}
  .text-xxl-right {text-align: right!important;}  

  /* float xxl */
  .float-xxl-left {float: left!important;}
  .float-xxl-right {float: right!important;}
  .float-xxl-none {float: none!important;}

  /* display xxl */
  .d-xxl-none {display: none!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline {display: inline!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline-block {display: inline-block!important;}
  .d-xxl-block {display: block!important;}
  .d-xxl-table {display: table!important;}
  .d-xxl-table-cell {display: table-cell!important;}
  .d-xxl-table-row {display: table-row!important;}
  .d-xxl-flex {display: flex!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline-flex {display: inline-flex!important;}

  /* offsets xxl */
  .offset-xxl-1 {margin-left: 8.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-2 {margin-left: 16.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
  .offset-xxl-4 {margin-left: 33.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-5 {margin-left: 41.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
  .offset-xxl-7 {margin-left: 58.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-8 {margin-left: 66.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
  .offset-xxl-10 {margin-left: 83.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-11 {margin-left: 91.666667%;}

  /* spacing xxl */
  .m-xxl-0{margin:0!important}.mt-xxl-0,.my-xxl-0{margin-top:0!important}.mr-xxl-0,.mx-xxl-0{margin-right:0!important}.mb-xxl-0,.my-xxl-0{margin-bottom:0!important}.ml-xxl-0,.mx-xxl-0{margin-left:0!important}.m-xxl-1{margin:.25rem!important}.mt-xxl-1,.my-xxl-1{margin-top:.25rem!important}.mr-xxl-1,.mx-xxl-1{margin-right:.25rem!important}.mb-xxl-1,.my-xxl-1{margin-bottom:.25rem!important}.ml-xxl-1,.mx-xxl-1{margin-left:.25rem!important}.m-xxl-2{margin:.5rem!important}.mt-xxl-2,.my-xxl-2{margin-top:.5rem!important}.mr-xxl-2,.mx-xxl-2{margin-right:.5rem!important}.mb-xxl-2,.my-xxl-2{margin-bottom:.5rem!important}.ml-xxl-2,.mx-xxl-2{margin-left:.5rem!important}.m-xxl-3{margin:1rem!important}.mt-xxl-3,.my-xxl-3{margin-top:1rem!important}.mr-xxl-3,.mx-xxl-3{margin-right:1rem!important}.mb-xxl-3,.my-xxl-3{margin-bottom:1rem!important}.ml-xxl-3,.mx-xxl-3{margin-left:1rem!important}.m-xxl-4{margin:1.5rem!important}.mt-xxl-4,.my-xxl-4{margin-top:1.5rem!important}.mr-xxl-4,.mx-xxl-4{margin-right:1.5rem!important}.mb-xxl-4,.my-xxl-4{margin-bottom:1.5rem!important}.ml-xxl-4,.mx-xxl-4{margin-left:1.5rem!important}.m-xxl-5{margin:3rem!important}.mt-xxl-5,.my-xxl-5{margin-top:3rem!important}.mr-xxl-5,.mx-xxl-5{margin-right:3rem!important}.mb-xxl-5,.my-xxl-5{margin-bottom:3rem!important}.ml-xxl-5,.mx-xxl-5{margin-left:3rem!important}
  .p-xxl-0{padding:0!important}.pt-xxl-0,.py-xxl-0{padding-top:0!important}.pr-xxl-0,.px-xxl-0{padding-right:0!important}.pb-xxl-0,.py-xxl-0{padding-bottom:0!important}.pl-xxl-0,.px-xxl-0{padding-left:0!important}.p-xxl-1{padding:.25rem!important}.pt-xxl-1,.py-xxl-1{padding-top:.25rem!important}.pr-xxl-1,.px-xxl-1{padding-right:.25rem!important}.pb-xxl-1,.py-xxl-1{padding-bottom:.25rem!important}.pl-xxl-1,.px-xxl-1{padding-left:.25rem!important}.p-xxl-2{padding:.5rem!important}.pt-xxl-2,.py-xxl-2{padding-top:.5rem!important}.pr-xxl-2,.px-xxl-2{padding-right:.5rem!important}.pb-xxl-2,.py-xxl-2{padding-bottom:.5rem!important}.pl-xxl-2,.px-xxl-2{padding-left:.5rem!important}.p-xxl-3{padding:1rem!important}.pt-xxl-3,.py-xxl-3{padding-top:1rem!important}.pr-xxl-3,.px-xxl-3{padding-right:1rem!important}.pb-xxl-3,.py-xxl-3{padding-bottom:1rem!important}.pl-xxl-3,.px-xxl-3{padding-left:1rem!important}.p-xxl-4{padding:1.5rem!important}.pt-xxl-4,.py-xxl-4{padding-top:1.5rem!important}.pr-xxl-4,.px-xxl-4{padding-right:1.5rem!important}.pb-xxl-4,.py-xxl-4{padding-bottom:1.5rem!important}.pl-xxl-4,.px-xxl-4{padding-left:1.5rem!important}.p-xxl-5{padding:3rem!important}.pt-xxl-5,.py-xxl-5{padding-top:3rem!important}.pr-xxl-5,.px-xxl-5{padding-right:3rem!important}.pb-xxl-5,.py-xxl-5{padding-bottom:3rem!important}.pl-xxl-5,.px-xxl-5{padding-left:3rem!important}
  .m-xxl-auto{margin:auto!important}.mt-xxl-auto,.my-xxl-auto{margin-top:auto!important}.mr-xxl-auto,.mx-xxl-auto{margin-right:auto!important}.mb-xxl-auto,.my-xxl-auto{margin-bottom:auto!important}.ml-xxl-auto,.mx-xxl-auto{margin-left:auto!important}

}
```

Now you will get full-supported XXL breakpoint. I know it's not the clearest solution, because we just overwriting Sass compiled code. If you have an ability to use Sass - do it, this way is more correct. But using CDN, like a quic-fix - can use my solution.

Comment: thx, there is small error at .col-xxl-10, 11, 12
And it is missing some container stuff:

.container-xxl {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1570px){
.container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl {max-width: 1540px;}
}

Answer (score 1):

According to Github it seems you're running into a 'bug' here. See here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1166

That being said you'd have to write your variable definition in a single line just like that.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (xxxs: 0, xxs: 320px, xs: 568px, sm: 667px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px, xxl: 1440px, xxxl: 1600px) !default
```

Comment: Thank you! it is fixing the bug, but doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you need just some part of CDN bootstrap adjusted and don't want to recompile you can add only relevant media boundaries. It's easier if you're adding breakpoints higher than -xl- (you load your .css update after you load bootstrap .css) or lower than xs (you load your .css update before bootstrap). Inserting a breakpoint in the middle is a little bit more tricky.

See https://www.codeply.com/p/ROF99teYDd where I've added **-xxl-** starting at **1550px** and **-mde-** for **840-992px**, purely in .css by duplicating required bootstrap media csss.

```
@media (min-width: 840px) and (max-width: 992px) {
 ...
 .col-mde-1 {
 -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
 flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
 max-width: 8.333333%;
 }
 .col-mde-2 {
   -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
   flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
   max-width: 16.666667%;
 }
 ...
 .col-mde-12 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1550px) {
 .col-xxl-1 {
   -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
   flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
   max-width: 8.333333%;
 }
...
}
```

Because of using min and max-width for the inserted elements, I need to specify the official bootstrap dimension for -lg- (min-width: 992px) to ensure the design doesn't break after this breakpoint.