# Extend the $grid-breakpoints map-merge variable through project variables file

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

In the Bootstrap _variables.scss file there is some code setting the breakpoint sizes

```
$grid-breakpoints: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$grid-breakpoints: map-merge(
  (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px
  ),
  $grid-breakpoints
);

@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints);
```

And I'm wondering if there is a way to add a new size to this list through a scss file outside of Bootstrap (since Bootstrap is through npm  and will be overriden on update)

The size I'm trying to add is `xxl: 1490px`

Comment: Are you just trying to add a new breakpoint? That's [exactty how customizations and overrides are done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924751/).. in a separate file.

Comment: Essentially yes, but I would like to keep the xs-xl sizes in the bootstrap variables file so they will stay current with bootstrap updates if they change.

Comment: They can stay there... just add the new breakpoint