# Bootstrap row element based on breakpoint

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and looping a div - but because bootstrap requires a parent div with the 'row' class, I need to print a row based on the number of divs within that. The only problem is, the examples I can find are all a set number, and I need to do it based on the breakpoint. For example, my code is:

```html
<div class="row">

  <?php foreach($projects as $project): ?>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">
        <a href="<?= $project->url() ?>" class="project_name"><?= $project->title()->html() ?></a>
          <?php if($image = $project->images()->sortBy('sort', 'asc')->first()): $thumb = $image->crop(600, 600); ?>
            <a href="<?= $project->url() ?>"><img src="<?= $thumb->url() ?>" alt="Thumbnail for <?= $project->title()->html() ?>" class="responsive" /></a>
          <?php endif ?>
          <p class="summary">
            <?php echo excerpt($project->problem(), 200) ?>
          </p>
        </a>
        <a href="<?= $project->url() ?>" class="btn project">Read More</a>
    </div>

  <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

As you can see, the child div in question that needs to be wrapped is 'col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12' meaning that on large devices the row parent should be printed every 3 divs, on medium every 2 and on small and extra small every 1.

Are there any ideas or examples on this? Such a hard thing to google and I'm out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use media breakpoints and customize column breakpoints look right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066059/bootstrap-3-adding-a-new-set-of-columns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to "print" the `row` every X cols. Put all of the cols in a single `.row`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">..</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">..</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">..</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">..</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project_box">..</div>
    ...
</div>
```

This is known as [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

However, if the content of each col varies in height, you will need to use "clearfix" responsive resets every X cols, **OR** make the columns the same height. Otherwise you'll have [the height problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311212/171456).