# Applying Bootstrap 3 grid to a special screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have two divs with `col-xs-12 col-md-9` and `col-xs-12 col-md-3`. They appear as expected

on a normal monitor:

[image]

on a phone screen:

[image]

And here is my issue. I have to adapt the layout to a special screen of 1300x1900 px. Yes, 1300 px width and 1900 px height. Right now it appears like this:

[image]

In this case I need something similar to the phone screen layout. Does Bootstrap 3 has something to handle this cases or should I do it manually?

Edit: adding custom screen widths to existing Bootsrap 3 grid doesn't really help. The issue is with screen ratio, not just the absolute screen size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 extra large (xl) columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256977/bootstrap-3-extra-large-xl-columns)

Answer (score 1):

here is the code for it:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
  <html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->


    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-12" style="background-color: red">
          abc</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-12" style="background-color: blue">
          def</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

check out thr fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/8sydhg9y/1/

Comment: unfortunately this not resolve my problem, as applying the simple bootstrap grid it takes into consideration only the absolut width of the screen and not the screen ratio, as I wrote in the description.

Comment: why?? whats  a problem in it i donot have a screen of 1300 1900 resolution how do i check but ihave already provided the thing for xl xtra large screens

Comment: check now i have added the latest bootstrap css library 4.1.smth

Comment: Seems to have no effect. Thanks anyway, I've managed to solve the problem manually.

Comment: you can give an upvote rather not an accepted answer

Comment: you can give it a green tick if my answers made you solve the problem manually